# FileUpload1.HasFile is always returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading file using ASP.net File upload control.
My FileUpload1.HasFile is always returning false.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            DBOperations db = new DBOperations();

            try
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedImages/" + db.uploadImage(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)) + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)));
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                String he = Ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

I am using following ASP.net Code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="fileUpload" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
             <Triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFile" EventName="Click" />
             </Triggers>
               <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> 
               <asp:Button ID="btnUploadFile" Text="Upload File" runat="server" 
                   onclick="btnUploadFile_Click" />
                   <br />
             <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revImage" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ValidationExpression="^.*\.((j|J)(p|P)(e|E)?(g|G)|(g|G)(i|I)(f|F)|(p|P)(n|N)(g|G))$" Text="Invalid image type" runat="server" />

          </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have tried even by removing AsyncPostBackTrigger and even by removing Whole asp:updatePanel then also my FileUpload1.HasFile always returns false.

Comment: When you remove the `UpdatePanel`, how you submit your form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET's "AJAX" thing doesn't support file uploads in UpdatePanels out of the box. Change that trigger into a `PostBackTrigger` (which causes a full page load) or use something else to upload the file.

Comment: should i use something of this type http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx

Comment: @Adam: That's one example of what you could use, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a trigger for your UpdatePanel

```
<Triggers> 
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFile" /> 
</Triggers>
```

This will force a postback when the upload button is clicked.

Also add the line below to the Page_Load

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post if old, but I found that if the file is empty [ 0 KB ] then it will return false as well. There has to be something in the file in order for .HasFile to acknowledge it.