# How to upload a file in asp.net in Tabbed interface control

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabbed-interface

I have a asp.net(c#) web application in that i am using Tabbed interface to show the forms.In Tabbed interface there are 4 tabs are there in 4th tab i have file upload control,when i try to upload a file it doesn't take the file it always show the null value .How can i upload the file in Tabbed interface please help me.

```
<cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Documents" ID="TabPanel4">
    <triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="SyncButton" />
    </triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="SyncButton" runat="server" Text="Test" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Documnets</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnfupload" runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="false" Text="Upload File"
                        OnClick="btnfupload_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</cc1:TabPanel>
```

Code Behind :

```
           protected void btnfupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            try
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("Documents")))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(MapPath("Documents"));

                    }
                    string docment = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(docment);
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Documents/") + path);

                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess the source of the problem is not the "tabbed interface". Would you please provide your code/markup ..

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i have post my code in question tag please find the code and help me please...

Comment: @Victor `btnfupload_Click` code pls...

Comment: while i upload file in normal page(without Tabbed interface)it is uploded correctly...

Comment: i using this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AJAXTabControl.aspx for tabbed interface in my project

Comment: u said `when i try to upload a file it doesn't take the file it always show the null value`. What shows `NULL`? u mean `FileUpload1.HasFile` is always `false` and it never passes the `if` condition?            **EDITED** also - FileUpload1 already has file name with extension. `FileUpload1.FileName` gives filename, no need to do the `string docment = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                    string path=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(docment);`

Comment: yes it always false it goes to else part.

Comment: ok thank you i can change that in my code,but need to FileUpload1.HasFile condition True ,,How?

Comment: Ajax and asp FileUpload... now ic whats causing problem. follow [The link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848523/fileupload1-hasfile-is-always-returning-false) or use the AsyncFileUpload as already suggested... or u can try to google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx):